# AmazonPay Update Auth Amount after address change

Tags: php, amazon-pay

I am setting up AmazonPay, all works great , until i have a address change to a country that will require an extra fee.
Ie to my country in UK shipping is Free , if they change it on address widget it will have already authorized an amount before this.

How do i re-authorize the changed amount ?
It has already used the getdetails page to auth original but does not give the address country until after the auth.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the amount after the authorization, but it is possible to get the address before and adjust the amount before completing the order.
To do so, you want to use the scope parameter for your button as documented here: https://amazonpaylegacyintegrationguide.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/amazon-pay-automatic/add-button-widget.html

The most exhaustive scope would be `'profile postal_code payments:widget payments:shipping_address payments:billing_address'`. You will receive an access token from Amazon which can be used in the GetOrderReferenceDetails details call during checkout as described here https://amazonpaylegacyintegrationguide.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/amazon-pay-api/getorderreferencedetails.html